# Flutter export fails with multiple build flavors

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build in build-flavors in my app. Android no problem but iOS gives an error when I try to export the ipa.

terminal:

```sh
➜  roger git:(ios-flavors) flutter build ios --flavor development
Building be.modero.rogerapp.development for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: **********
Running pod install...                                              7.8s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        24.1s
Xcode build done.                                           179.1s
Built /.../build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.
➜  roger git:(ios-flavors) xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Alpha -workspace ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme development build -verbose | xcpretty
```

error:

```
▸ Compiling GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m

❌  /.../ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: module 'camera' not found

@import camera;
^


▸ Compiling Runner_vers.c
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/wim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dhynqmoqlyqjqtaxqfpznxnuxyab/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-integration-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o /.../ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
(1 failure)
```

Comment: hI, did u solved this issue?

Comment: Yeah everything works now but I don't remember the exact solution. Sorry